# Graph Editor does not show any keyframes

Tags: graph-editor, fcurves

I already made and rigged a character. When I make keyframes in the dopesheet to time my animation, the graph editor does not show any of my keyframes, for any of my animated parts. Even when I go to check the drivers, the driver pane is completely blank, just an empty graph as well.

The weird part is, a couple of sessions ago, it was working completely fine, because I know I was able to edit drivers then. So what could possibly be happening here? I unfortunately cant share the blend file due to the fact that it belongs to the project group I work with, but I was hoping for some general pointers on how I can figure this out. Keep in mind my dope sheet and NLA editor works completely fine, it's just the graph editor.

Here is an image of what it currently looks like:

[image: empty graph editor]

and here is the corresponding dope sheet for the same animation:
[image: dope sheet with the keyframes showing]

Comment: post an image that displays the bottom part of your graph editor window (the part where there is a ghost, a life saver and filters)

Comment: i posted two images just now, do those fit what you are talking about?

Comment: ...oh my god... thank you for pointing out the bottom of the panel. apparently when i click ghost all my curves MAGICALLY appear. so many hours i have wasted at this issue.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you have hidden objects or bones they won't show in the graph editor window unless you enable the switch to display them.

[image]

In Blender today the icons looks like this:

[image]

More info here: https://docs.blender.org/manual/en/latest/editors/graph_editor/index.html

Answer (score 1):

ok if fcurves are missing, click the little ghost icon at the bottom of the graph editor pane. apparently if that is off your curves wont show...why would they design it like that though?