# Channels and keys of animated bones do not appear on Graph Editor

Tags: animation, bones, graph-editor

So I animated bones on an armature, things were normal for a long time. Today I decided to mess with the animation and to my surprise the keys are gone! The animation still plays normally, and the keys appear on the timeline, but channels and keys are nowhere to be found on the Graph Editor when selecting a bone.

I tried:

*Copying and pasting the same keys on the same channels on the same place or different places on the timeline to see if they would magically appear but it didn't work (by the way it works when copy-pasting keys from a bone to another, just create a key first then paste on the same channel)

*Messing with some controls on the Graph Editor that makes curves visible or hidden, and they didn't work

*Creating keys for the armature works but the keys are hidden too

*Creating keys for different objects, and it works. So the problem is not general, it's specific for the armature's bones

Can't provide the file right now but I guess that's enough info. By the way I am using version 2.79b. Researched a little bit to see if someone also had the problem. It seems to be a new thing.

Comment: maybe you've pushed your action down into the NLA? Please share your file (just the armature)

Answer (score 2):

Problem answered here:
[Graph Editor does not show any keyframes](https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/47818/graph-editor-does-not-show-any-keyframes/47821)

Apparently the button "show_hidden" on the view controls at the botton on Graph Editor must be set to true to allow the visualization of keys from objects or bones that are "hidden". To the right is the button "show_only_errors" to show only keys with errors or a red bar under (usually unupdated or related to a deleted object/bone/shape key) and to the left is the button "show_only_selected" for showing only keys from objects you selected, which if set to "false" makes all keys from any object and bone appear.

[image]
*Examples made from Blender 2.79b. The buttons do the same thing and are on the same place on the newest Blender's version to date

I cannot explain the status of "hidden" yet. It doesn't seem to have anything to do with "hidden from view", it is another type of "hidden"